# Cancelar submit de form si un campo esta vacio

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy intentando hacer que un formulario se cancele si al momento de enviarlo uno de los campos esta vacio y quiero que el mensaje cambie dependiendo si un check esta seleccionado o no.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El sistema deberia revisar si el campo de indicaciones esta vacio para mostrar el mensaje y que el usuario lo llene. Tambien quiero que cambie si en el campo de direccion aproximada esta la direccion por default cuando carga la API de Google Maps.

El codigo que uso es el siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


var hvalue = "";


$("#direccion").on("submit", function (e) {   


    if($('#chkbxDireccion').is(':checked')){

        if( $("#txtind").val() ){
            alert("El texto esta vacio");
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        else{

            hvalue = $('#txtdir').val();

            $('.direccion_div').val(hvalue);


        }

    }


    else{

        if( $("#txtind").val() ){
            alert("El texto esta vacio");
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        else{

            hvalue = $('.direccion_div').text();

        }
    }


    $(this).append("<input type='hidden' name='dir' value=' " + hvalue + " '/>");


});
});
```

Lo unico que no funciona son los if donde verifica el input con el ID de "txtind".

De antemano gracias por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que tu problema está: **if($("#txtind").val())**, porque a mi criterio, creo que será más preciso saber si el largo del texto es mayor a 0. Mi propuesta sería la siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var hvalue = "";

    $("#direccion").on("submit", function (e) {   
        if($('#chkbxDireccion').is(':checked')){
            if( $("#txtind").val().length < 1 ){
                alert("El texto esta vacio");
                e.preventDefault();
            } else {
                hvalue = $('#txtdir').val();
                $('.direccion_div').val(hvalue);
            }
        } else {
            if($("#txtind").val().length < 1 ){
               alert("El texto esta vacio");
               e.preventDefault();
            } else {
                hvalue = $('.direccion_div').text();
            }
        }

        $(this).append("<input type='hidden' name='dir' value=' " + hvalue + " '/>");
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow, asi de facil. Muchas gracias amigo